# How to convert a complex JavaScript array to a PHP array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array like this:

```
var f3_masks = [
    [
        {id: 0, id_name: '1-1', db_id: '3193586'},
        {id: 10, id_name: '3-4', db_id: '3193636'},
        {id: 20, id_name: '3-5', db_id: '3193636'}
    ],
    page2_fl = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],

    page2_fr = [
        './images/korpus1/floors/floor_3.jpg'
    ]
];

var f4_masks = [
    [
        {id: 0, id_name: '1-1', db_id: '3193586'},
        {id: 10, id_name: '3-4', db_id: '3193636'},
        {id: 20, id_name: '3-5', db_id: '3193636'}
    ]
];
```

etc. It's a pretty large set of arrays with thousands of strings. Part of it I can parse as JSON, but only part of it. What is the best way to read such JavaScript arrays without a regular stucture in PHP?

Comment: Didn't vote down, but that looks like a syntax error.

Comment: JSON will work for you

Comment: How wouild it work? It is not valid JSON array.

Comment: Mario, thank you. Very similar questions, but not exactly my case. I have a set of vars, not just one.

Answer (score -1):

Keys must be in double quotes:

"page2_fl"

Try to use the checking service at http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: I cannot change format of this array. I need to parse it in PHP as is.